# How can my geth listen to my domain,

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, json-rpc, geth-clique

i have setup my geth private node on my ubuntu server and sofar so good localhost running perfectly. and now i really want to use my domain http://rpc.example.com instead of http://localhost:8545. and i have been read the docs how to use http interface, and a couple tutorial like https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/geth/
but got no luck. i guest i miss some configuration in here, and need more info from you guys what i doing wrong.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/geth.conf

```
server {
  listen 8545; //80 does not work
  listen [::]:8545; //80 does not work
  server_name rpc.domainname.com;

  location / {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        return 204;
     }

    auth_basic          off;

    add_header          Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "$http_origin";
    add_header          Access-Control-Allow-Headers "authorization, content-type";
    add_header          Access-Control-Allow-Methods "DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, UPDATE";

    proxy_hide_header   Access-Control-Allow-Origin;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection          "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://172.0.0.1:5469/;
  }
}
```

geth

```
geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --http --http.addr '0.0.0.0' --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "http://rpc.domainname.com" -http.api 'eth,net,web3,txpool,personal' --bootnodes 'enode://example_enode7@127.0.0.1:8545?discport=30310' --networkid 119 --miner.gasprice '1' -unlock '0x6e...' --password node1/account/password.txt --mine --allow-insecure-unlock --snapshot=false
```

Thank you for anykind of suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Should be use parameter `--http.vhosts "rpc.domainname.com"`

Reference https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options